# Pine script : create linear regression fixed interval line with standard error, r-squared, and angle of line readouts

Tags: regression, linear-regression, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to be able to plot a linear regression line(fixed interval straight trend line, not a continuous curve) from any two start and end price bars on a stock chart. Tradingview has a regression TREND tool that allows you to draw it on the chart, instead of entering the dates manually. This tool is easier, but I cant find the code for it, so a manual date entry box is also fine.  I would like that regression trendline to appear on the chart, then state the standard error of each bar, making it easy to note the most extreme outliers. If possible, having r-squared added to this line as a readout would also be an excellent comparative tool (to help determine weakest r-squared). Lastly, I want some type of ANGLE measurement of the linear regression trendline; Angle of line, or Slope? Attached is tradingview's built-in Linear regression Channel indicator code as a starting point. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

````
```
//@version=5
indicator("Linear Regression Channel", shorttitle="LinReg", overlay=true)

lengthInput = input.int(100, title="Length", minval = 1, maxval = 5000)
sourceInput = input.source(close, title="Source")

group1 = "Channel Settings"
useUpperDevInput = input.bool(true, title="Upper Deviation", inline = "Upper Deviation", group = group1)
upperMultInput = input.float(2.0, title="", inline = "Upper Deviation", group = group1)
useLowerDevInput = input.bool(true, title="Lower Deviation", inline = "Lower Deviation", group = group1)
lowerMultInput = input.float(2.0, title="", inline = "Lower Deviation", group = group1)

group2 = "Display Settings"
showPearsonInput = input.bool(true, "Show Pearson's R", group = group2)
extendLeftInput = input.bool(false, "Extend Lines Left", group = group2)
extendRightInput = input.bool(true, "Extend Lines Right", group = group2)
extendStyle = switch
    extendLeftInput and extendRightInput => extend.both
    extendLeftInput => extend.left
    extendRightInput => extend.right
    => extend.none

group3 = "Color Settings"
colorUpper = input.color(color.new(color.blue, 85), "", inline = group3, group = group3)
colorLower = input.color(color.new(color.red, 85), "", inline = group3, group = group3)

calcSlope(source, length) =>
    max_bars_back(source, 5000)
    if not barstate.islast or length <= 1
        [float(na), float(na), float(na)]
    else
        sumX = 0.0
        sumY = 0.0
        sumXSqr = 0.0
        sumXY = 0.0
        for i = 0 to length - 1 by 1
            val = source[i]
            per = i + 1.0
            sumX += per
            sumY += val
            sumXSqr += per * per
            sumXY += val * per
        slope = (length * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (length * sumXSqr - sumX * sumX)
        average = sumY / length
        intercept = average - slope * sumX / length + slope
        [slope, average, intercept]
        
[s, a, i] = calcSlope(sourceInput, lengthInput)
startPrice = i + s * (lengthInput - 1)
endPrice = i
var line baseLine = na
if na(baseLine) and not na(startPrice)
    baseLine := line.new(bar_index - lengthInput + 1, startPrice, bar_index, endPrice, width=1, extend=extendStyle, color=color.new(colorLower, 0))
else
    line.set_xy1(baseLine, bar_index - lengthInput + 1, startPrice)
    line.set_xy2(baseLine, bar_index, endPrice)
    na
    
calcDev(source, length, slope, average, intercept) =>
    upDev = 0.0
    dnDev = 0.0
    stdDevAcc = 0.0
    dsxx = 0.0
    dsyy = 0.0
    dsxy = 0.0
    periods = length - 1
    daY = intercept + slope * periods / 2
    val = intercept
    for j = 0 to periods by 1
        price = high[j] - val
        if price > upDev
            upDev := price
        price := val - low[j]
        if price > dnDev
            dnDev := price
        price := source[j]
        dxt = price - average
        dyt = val - daY
        price -= val
        stdDevAcc += price * price
        dsxx += dxt * dxt
        dsyy += dyt * dyt
        dsxy += dxt * dyt
        val += slope
    stdDev = math.sqrt(stdDevAcc / (periods == 0 ? 1 : periods))
    pearsonR = dsxx == 0 or dsyy == 0 ? 0 : dsxy / math.sqrt(dsxx * dsyy)
    [stdDev, pearsonR, upDev, dnDev]
    
[stdDev, pearsonR, upDev, dnDev] = calcDev(sourceInput, lengthInput, s, a, i)
upperStartPrice = startPrice + (useUpperDevInput ? upperMultInput * stdDev : upDev)
upperEndPrice = endPrice + (useUpperDevInput ? upperMultInput * stdDev : upDev)
var line upper = na
lowerStartPrice = startPrice + (useLowerDevInput ? -lowerMultInput * stdDev : -dnDev)
lowerEndPrice = endPrice + (useLowerDevInput ? -lowerMultInput * stdDev : -dnDev)
var line lower = na
if na(upper) and not na(upperStartPrice)
    upper := line.new(bar_index - lengthInput + 1, upperStartPrice, bar_index, upperEndPrice, width=1, extend=extendStyle, color=color.new(colorUpper, 0))
else
    line.set_xy1(upper, bar_index - lengthInput + 1, upperStartPrice)
    line.set_xy2(upper, bar_index, upperEndPrice)
    na
if na(lower) and not na(lowerStartPrice)
    lower := line.new(bar_index - lengthInput + 1, lowerStartPrice, bar_index, lowerEndPrice, width=1, extend=extendStyle, color=color.new(colorUpper, 0))
else
    line.set_xy1(lower, bar_index - lengthInput + 1, lowerStartPrice)
    line.set_xy2(lower, bar_index, lowerEndPrice)
    na
linefill.new(upper, baseLine, color = colorUpper)
linefill.new(baseLine, lower, color = colorLower)
    
// Pearson's R
var label r = na
label.delete(r[1])
if showPearsonInput and not na(pearsonR)
    r := label.new(bar_index - lengthInput + 1, lowerStartPrice, str.tostring(pearsonR, "#.################"), color = color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.new(colorUpper, 0), size=size.normal, style=label.style_label_up)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `confirm = true` argument with `input.time()` in order to manually click start and end points.

Since we have to render something like the individual errors historically, we have to use the label functions to do so. There is a 500 label limit, so if the regression contains more than 500 bars, then you will have to define "extreme outliers" in this context in order to limit outliers to 500 labelled bars or less.

````
//@version=5
indicator("point to point linreg", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500, max_labels_count = 500)

start_time = input.time(timestamp("20 Jul 2022 00:00 +000"), title = "Start time", confirm = true)
end_time = input.time(timestamp("21 Jul 2022 00:00 +000"), title = "End time", confirm = true)
src = input.source(close, title = "Source")
devmult = input.float(1.000, title = "Dev mult")
reg_line_col = input.color(color.blue, title = "Reg line color")
up_line_col = input.color(color.green, title = "Upper Dev line color")
dn_line_col = input.color(color.red, title = "Lower Dev line color")
reg_line_width = input.int(2, title = "Line width")

f_linreg_from_arrays(_x_array, _y_array) =>
    _size_x = array.size(_x_array)
    _size_y = array.size(_y_array)
    
    float _sum_x = array.sum(_x_array)
    float _sum_y = array.sum(_y_array)
    float _sum_xy = 0.0
    float _sum_x2 = 0.0
    float _sum_y2 = 0.0

    if _size_y == _size_x
        for _i = 0 to _size_y - 1
            float _x_i = nz(array.get(_x_array, _i))
            float _y_i = nz(array.get(_y_array, _i))
            _sum_xy := _sum_xy + _x_i * _y_i
            _sum_x2 := _sum_x2 + math.pow(_x_i, 2)
            _sum_y2 := _sum_y2 + math.pow(_y_i, 2)
            _sum_y2

    float _a = (_sum_y * _sum_x2 - _sum_x * _sum_xy) / (_size_x * _sum_x2 - math.pow(_sum_x, 2))
    float _b = (_size_x * _sum_xy - _sum_x * _sum_y) / (_size_x * _sum_x2 - math.pow(_sum_x, 2))

    float[] _f = array.new_float()

    for _i = 0 to _size_y - 1
        float _vector = _a + _b * array.get(_x_array, _i)
        array.push(_f, _vector)

    _slope = (array.get(_f, 0) - array.get(_f, _size_y - 1)) / (array.get(_x_array, 0) - array.get(_x_array, _size_x - 1))
    _y_mean = array.avg(_y_array)

    float _SS_res = 0.0
    float _SS_tot = 0.0

    for _i = 0 to _size_y - 1
        float _f_i = array.get(_f, _i)
        float _y_i = array.get(_y_array, _i)
        _SS_res := _SS_res + math.pow(_f_i - _y_i, 2)
        _SS_tot := _SS_tot + math.pow(_y_mean - _y_i, 2)
        _SS_tot

    _r_sq = 1 - _SS_res / _SS_tot

    float _sq_err_sum = 0

    for _i = 0 to _size_y - 1
        _sq_err_sum += math.pow(array.get(_f, _i) - array.get(_y_array, _i), 2)

    _dev = math.sqrt(_sq_err_sum / _size_y)

    [_f, _slope, _r_sq, _dev]


var int[] time_vals = array.new_int()
var float[] price_vals = array.new_float()

var line[] reg_lines = array.new_line()
var line[] up_lines = array.new_line()
var line[] dn_lines = array.new_line()

var label reg_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, xloc = xloc.bar_time, style = label.style_label_upper_left, textcolor = color.white, textalign = text.align_left)

is_last_bar = time >= end_time and time[1] < end_time
is_in_time_range = time >= start_time and time <= end_time

if is_in_time_range
    array.unshift(time_vals, time)
    array.unshift(price_vals, src)


if barstate.isfirst
    for i = 0 to 165
        array.push(reg_lines, line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = reg_line_col, width = reg_line_width))
        array.push(up_lines, line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = up_line_col, width = reg_line_width))
        array.push(dn_lines, line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = dn_line_col, width = reg_line_width))

if is_last_bar
    [f, slope, r_sq, dev] = f_linreg_from_arrays(time_vals, price_vals)
    size = array.size(time_vals)
    
    if size > 0
        if size <= 167
            for i = 0 to size - 2
                start_x = array.get(time_vals, i)
                start_y = array.get(f, i)
                end_x = array.get(time_vals, i + 1)
                end_y = array.get(f, i + 1)
                reg_line = array.get(reg_lines, i)
                up_line = array.get(up_lines, i)
                dn_line = array.get(dn_lines, i)
                line.set_xy1(reg_line, x = start_x, y = start_y)
                line.set_xy2(reg_line, x = end_x, y = end_y)
        else
            interval = math.ceil(size / 166)
            line_index = 0
            for i = 0 to size - math.floor(interval / 2) - 2 by interval
                index2 = i + math.floor(interval / 2)
                start_x = array.get(time_vals, i)
                start_y = array.get(f, i)
                end_x = array.get(time_vals, index2)
                end_y = array.get(f, index2)
                reg_line = array.get(reg_lines, line_index)
                up_line = array.get(up_lines, line_index)
                dn_line = array.get(dn_lines, line_index)
                line.set_xy1(reg_line, x = start_x, y = start_y)
                line.set_xy2(reg_line, x = end_x, y = end_y)
                line.set_xy1(up_line, x = start_x, y = start_y + devmult * dev)
                line.set_xy2(up_line, x = end_x, y = end_y + devmult * dev)
                line.set_xy1(dn_line, x = start_x, y = start_y - devmult * dev)
                line.set_xy2(dn_line, x = end_x, y = end_y - devmult * dev)
                line_index += 1
        
        reg_info = "Slope : " + str.tostring(slope) + "\nR² : " + str.tostring(r_sq) + "\ndev : " + str.tostring(dev)
        
        label_x = array.get(time_vals, 0)
        label_y = array.get(f, 0) - devmult * dev
        label.set_xy(reg_label, x = label_x, y = label_y)
        label.set_text(reg_label, text = reg_info)```
````